# Conditions on a permutation of $\mathbf{N}$ such that rearrangements of series don't change convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm doing exercises from Dieudonné's *Foundations of modern analysis*. Problems 5.2.2 and 5.2.3 are concerned with conditions under which rearrangements of series converge.

---

Let $E$ be a normed space (not necessarily complete), $(x_n)$ a sequence of elements of $E$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ exists, and $\sigma$ a permutation of $\mathbf{N}$. When does $\sum x_{\sigma(n)}$ converge with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{\sigma(n)}$?

The first condition is only about $\sigma$: It says that this is true regardless of the series if and only if the number of "gaps" in $\sigma([0,n])$ is bounded in $n$.

The second condition states that $\sum x_{\sigma(n)}$ converges to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(|\sigma(n)-n|\sup_{m\geq n}\lVert x_m\rVert\right)=0.$$

---

I'm unable to prove the second condition. So I'd appreciate a hint. Maybe someone also can reference some textbooks or articles where these and similar results are treated in a more systematical fashion.