# Mysterious Series Rearrangement/Permutation Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, permutations, banach-spaces

This problem appears in J. Dieudonne's "Foundations of Foundations of Modern Analysis". (chapter 5, section 2):

Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent series in a normed space $E$; let $\sigma$ be a bijection of $N$ onto itself, and let 
$$r(n) = |\sigma(n) - n| \cdot \sup_{m \geq n}\|x_m\|.$$
Show that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}r(n) = 0$, the series $(x_{\sigma(n)})$ is convergent in $E$ and that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_{\sigma(n)}$.

Any ideas about a solution? A similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492193/conditions-on-a-permutation-of-mathbfn-such-that-rearrangements-of-series-d) from a couple years ago came up dry.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(k):= |\sigma(k)-k|$ can be seen as the 'local discrepancy' of the permutation. If $f(k)$ is bounded, it is easy to see that the correspondig series converges and has the same limit.

I need additionally that
$$ \widetilde{r}(n) := |\sigma(n)-n| \sup_{k \geq \min(n,\sigma(n))} \|x_i\| \rightarrow 0$$
in order to prove the above result: First, we observe that for all $m \geq M$, where $M$ is chosen later,
$$ \| \sum_{k=1}^m x_k - \sum_{k=1}^m x_{\sigma(k)}\| \leq \max_{i \in B \setminus A} \|x_i\| \# (B \setminus A) + \sup_{i \in A \setminus B} \|x_i\| \# (A \setminus B),$$
where $A:= \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $B:= \{\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(m)\}$.

Fix $N$ with $\widetilde{r}(n) < \varepsilon$ for any $n \geq N$ and take $M$ so large that

- $\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(N) \leq M$
- $\{1,\ldots,N\} \subset \{\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(M)\}$.

Now take $\sigma(k) \in B \setminus A$ with minimal $1 \leq k \leq m$. Then $$\# B \setminus A \leq m -(k-1) \leq \sigma(k)-k.$$

Then we must have $k > N$. Noting that $\sigma(h) > m \geq k$ for any $h \in B \setminus A$, we find 
$$\max_{h \in B \setminus A} \|x_i\| \# (B \setminus A) \leq \max_{i \geq k} \|x_i\| |\sigma(k)-k| = \widetilde{r}(k) \leq \varepsilon.$$

If $h \in A \setminus B$, then $\sigma(l) = h$ with $l > m$ and $h >N$. Thus, taking $h$ minimal, we get again $\# A \setminus B \leq m - (h-1) \leq l - \sigma(l)$. Using this, shows that
$$\sup_{i \in A \setminus B} \|x_i\| \# (A \setminus B) \leq \sup_{i >\sigma(l)} \|x_i\| |l-\sigma(l)| \leq \widetilde{r}(l) \leq \varepsilon$$
because $l > m \geq M  \geq N$.

However, I am not sure, if the additional requirement is necessary.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks for the reply (and edit)! I actually had considered the strengthened condition (for $\tilde r(n)$) as well. Otherwise, handling A\B is quite difficult.

Comment: The question is whether the strengthened condition is necessary or not. Maybe it is possible to prove my condition using $r(n) \rightarrow 0$ and the convergence of the series?